# Issue with z-index and position absolute

Tags: css, z-index, absolute

I have problem with z-index again.
Please check page

http://webakery.asia/projects/valentine/

On the right side I have absolutely positioned picture with flowers, but they are overlaping navigation and eventually affect functionality of links in navigation. I want to hide those flowers behind navigation.
I have been playing around with z-indexes, but still cannot figure out the way. Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your `z-index: 100` to `z-index` less than 50 (your navigation z-index) for  `section`, e.g.

```
section {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 960px;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

and add `position: relative` to your `nav`

```
nav {
    background: url("../images/bg-menu.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    min-height: 66px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think div.flowers should be outside of your  tag

try this.. make the z-index on section -1 and look how everything goes behind your nav.

i think you should move div.flowers outside of your  block and then assign its z-index independently.  As is, you can change it all day, but the z-index that matters belongs to